# How to create a CUPS service for mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, uri, cloud-foundry

I am currently using a local database. Using a terminal to access mongodb.

These are all the credentials I have. In my application properties when I provide the following data I am able to retrieve and store data.

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=myNewDB
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
```

I am trying to use cloud foundry CUPS to connect mongodb with URI.
But following the URI guide line I am missing username and password. Where can I find those values? All my data is currently stored locally and do not wish to use the MongoDB that is provided by Cloud Foundry because I would have to manually enter those data again.

```
DB-TYPE://USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOSTNAME:PORT/NAME
mongo://don't:know@localhost:27017/myNewDB
```

**Attempt**

In mongo shell I did the following to create an admin.

```
use admin
db.createUser(
   {
     user: "appAdmin",
     pwd: "password",
     roles:
       [
         { role: "readWrite", db: "myNewDB" },
         "clusterAdmin"
       ]
   }
)
```

After this I added the following into my application.properties

```
spring.data.mongodb.username=appAdmin
spring.data.mongodb.password=password
```

When I run my application I receive the following error:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=null, userName='appAdmin', source='myNewDB', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties={}}
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslAuthenticator.java:61) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultAuthenticator.authenticate(DefaultAuthenticator.java:32) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.authenticateAll(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:99) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:44) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:128) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18: 'Authentication failed.' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "code" : 18, "errmsg" : "Authentication failed." }
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.createCommandFailureException(CommandHelper.java:170) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.receiveCommandResult(CommandHelper.java:123) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:32) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.sendSaslStart(SaslAuthenticator.java:95) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslAuthenticator.java:45) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar:na]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

but when I remove username and password from my application.properties file. My application would run as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Username and password in your context means the username password for MongoDB.
MongoDB authentication is optional. You can start mongod without authentication. but this is not recommended in Production systems. 
You can enable authentication for mongodb and create users in it to access.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication

You can create and bind CUPS service with your mongodb params to your application. Then you can read this service in an environment variable VCAP_SERVICES.
System.getEnv("VCAP_SERVICES");
You can also write a custom connector to read the configurations if you are using Spring cloud.
https://spring.io/blog/2014/08/05/extending-spring-cloud

Also remember you may need to create Security Groups in CF to open ports to connect cloud foundry to local network.
https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/asg.html

Comment: I see you said that it is optional. But if I want to create a CUPS service with my local mongodb would it still be optional? How would the uri look like?

Comment: I created a username and password, also given roles to it.But when I add spring.data.mongodb.username and password. I receive authentication errors.