# How to connect a database server running on local machine as a service to web application hosted on pivotal cloud foundry?

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, cloud-foundry

I am trying to test run a basic .NET web application on pivotal cloud foundry. This web application uses as its database a MongoDB server hosted on my local machine. At the moment I am limited to use of the cloud infrastructure by using just the Apps Manager.

I have read the pivotal cloud foundry docs about user provided services, but cannot figure out as to how the connection is to be really made. I have already come across various other ways like using MongoDB as a service (beta version), but at the moment I am not allowed access to the Operations Manager. Looking for an explanation on user provided services or how to implement the service broker API, specifically.

I am new to Mongo as well, so any suggestion regarding making a connection through tweaking Mongo may help as well. Thanks

Comment: Question is too broad for the Stackoverflow @Soham basu

Comment: Kind of thinking this should be asked directly to The Pivotal Cloud Foundary support. My understanding is that is a "paid service" and therefore since money is coming out of your pocket, then it makes little sense to ask for community help for something a representative should be able to handle.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This appears to be a Question for Pivotal Cloud Foundary support.

Comment: The service is not a paid service. It is a Mongo server running on my local machine, not deployed by any IaaS cloud service provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use case you describe (web app in PCF connecting to a resource in your local machine) is not recommended.

You can create a MongoDB instance for development purposes in PCF.

```
$ cf marketplace  
...  
mlab    sandbox       Fully managed MongoDB-as-a-Service  
...
```

You can create a `mlab` service and bind it to your application.  You will then have a MongoDB instance in PCF that you can use for development purposes.

---

Edit:
In that case a user provided service might help you, where you pass in your remote MongoDB instance configuration that you can read in your application. e.g.:

```
cf.exe cups my-mongodb -p '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}'
```

Comment: one clarification - I will need the Ops manager to register mlab service broker so that it shows up on the marketplace; or implement the service broker API myself which would require admin access, neither of which is available to me right now. Is there any way to bypass the service broker altogether?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your local mongo-db as a CUPS service to your PCF Dev.

Check out the following post.
[How to create a CUPS service for mongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43878143/how-to-create-a-cups-service-for-mongodb)